# Crontab works incorrectly

Tags: cron

I have a job set to run as per below cron schedule

```
0,15,30,45 * 8-17 * 1-5
```

However, instead of running only on Mon to Fri and only from 8th to 17th of the month, this job runs every 15 mins (including weekends and days of month other that 8th to 17th). I am unsure if the problem is with the number ranges or other place.

Comment: I notice that the job runs fine if I write Mon, Tue....Fri, however, if I write 1-5 then it kicks off even on a weekend

Comment: If my answer solved your problem please select it as accepted by clicking the tick mark on the left of my answer so that this issue can be marked as solved..

Answer (score 1):

From `man 5 crontab` :

> The day of a command's execution can be specified by two fields — day 
>   of  month,  and  day  of  week.   If  both  fields  are
>          restricted (i.e., aren't *), the command will be run when either field matches the current time.  For example,
>          ``30 4 1,15 * 5'' would cause a command to be run at 4:30 am on the 1st and 15th of each month, plus every Friday. One can, however,
>          achieve the desired result by adding a test to the command.

So in your case the command is being executed on date `8-17` of all months **plus** `mon-fri` of every week.

In order to run the job on only `mon-fri` of day `8-17` of each month we need to add a test :

```
*/15 * 8-17 * * /bin/bash -c '[[ $(/bin/date '+%u') =~ 1|2|3|4|5 ]]' && your_command
```

The above job will be run after every 15 minutes of `8-17` of each month and will check if the day is between monday to friday by the test `[[ $(/bin/date '+%u') =~ 1|2|3|4|5 ]]`, if so then `your_command` will be executed, otherwise not.

Also as you are using an interval of 15 minutes use `*/15` instead of comma separated range.